# Is locking necessary in this ConcurrentDictionary caching scenario

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency

I have the following code to cache instances of some class in a Concurrent Dictionary to which I use in a multi threaded application.

Simply, when I instantinate the class with the id parameter, it first checks if an instance of privateclass with the given id exists in the dictionary, and if not creates an instance of the privateclass (which takes long time, sometimes couple of seconds), and adds it to the dictionary for future use.

```
public class SomeClass
{
    private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<int, PrivateClass> SomeClasses =
        new ConcurrentDictionary<int, PrivateClass>();

    private readonly PrivateClass _privateClass;

    public SomeClass(int cachedInstanceId)
    {
        if (!SomeClasses.TryGetValue(cachedInstanceId, out _privateClass))
        {
            _privateClass = new PrivateClass(); // This takes long time
            SomeClasses.TryAdd(cachedInstanceId, _privateClass);
        }
    }

    public int SomeCalculationResult()
    {
        return _privateClass.CalculateSomething();
    }

    private class PrivateClass
    {
        internal PrivateClass()
        {
            // this takes long time
        }

        internal int CalculateSomething()
        {
            // Calculates and returns something
        }
    }
}
```

My question is, do I need to add a lock around the generation and assignment part of the outer classes constructor to make this code thread safe or is it good as it is?

Update:

After SLaks's [suggestion](http://reedcopsey.com/2011/01/16/concurrentdictionarytkeytvalue-used-with-lazyt/), tried to use [GetOrAdd()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee378677.aspx) method of ConcurrentDictionary with the combination of [Lazy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331.aspx), but unfortunately the constructor of the `PrivateClass` still called more than once. See https://gist.github.com/3500955 for the test code.

Update 2:
You can see the final solution here:
https://gist.github.com/3501446

Comment: Solution: https://gist.github.com/3501446

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're misusing `ConcurrentDictionary`.

In multi-threaded code, you should never check for the presence of an item, then add it if it's not there.
If two threads run that code at once, they will both end up adding it.

In general, there are two solutions tho this kind of problem.  You can wrap all of that code in a lock, or you can redesign it to the whole thing in one atomic operation.

`ConcurrentDictionary` is designed to for this kind of scenario.

You should simply call

```
 _privateClass = SomeClasses.GetOrAdd(cachedInstanceId, key => new PrivateClass());
```

Comment: With this usage, what will happen to the other threads which are trying to get the value, while the constructor of the `PrivateClass` is executing? Will they wait for the item to be added?

Comment: @MennanKara http://ayende.com/blog/4802/concurrentdictionary-getoradd-may-call-the-valuefactory-method-more-than-once http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee378677.aspx

Comment: `GetOrAdd` is not atomic. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997369.aspx

Comment: @mikez: But its guaranteed to return a single consistent value.

Comment: @Slaks Yes but the constructor of `PrivateClass` could be called twice which is what I think the OP is trying to avoid since it takes a long time. If is ok to possibly call it twice then `GetOrAdd` is fine.

Comment: @MennanKara: See http://reedcopsey.com/2011/01/16/concurrentdictionarytkeytvalue-used-with-lazyt/

Comment: The constructor of the actual privateclass is creating a full text index for a database of products of tens of thousands. I really wouldn't want it to work twice, I would prefer other threads to wait for the index build request of the first thread.

Comment: Unfortunately, the Lazy<T> solution didn't work as I expected. See https://gist.github.com/3500955

Comment: @MennanKara: Calling `.Value` in the factory defeats the purpose.  (that's the same as `new SomeClass()`)  You need to store the `Lazy<T>` in the dictionary.

Answer (score 7):

Locking is not necessary, but what you're doing is not thread-safe.  Instead of first checking the dictionary for presence of an item and then adding it if necessary, you should use [`ConcurrentDictionary.GetOrAdd()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee378677.aspx) to do it all in one atomic operation.

Otherwise, you're exposing yourself to the same problem that you'd have with a regular dictionary: another thread might add an entry to `SomeClasses` after you check for existence but before you insert.

Answer (score 3):

Your sample code at https://gist.github.com/3500955 using ConcurrentDictionary and Lazy<T> is incorrect - you're writing:

```
    private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<int, PrivateClass> SomeClasses =
        new ConcurrentDictionary<int, PrivateClass>();
    public SomeClass(int cachedInstanceId)
    {
        _privateClass = SomeClasses.GetOrAdd(cachedInstanceId, (key) => new Lazy<PrivateClass>(() => new PrivateClass(key)).Value);
    }
```

..which should have been:

```
    private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<int, Lazy<PrivateClass>> SomeClasses =
        new ConcurrentDictionary<int, Lazy<PrivateClass>>();
    public SomeClass(int cachedInstanceId)
    {
        _privateClass = SomeClasses.GetOrAdd(cachedInstanceId, (key) => new Lazy<PrivateClass>(() => new PrivateClass(key))).Value;
    }
```

You need to use ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, Lazy<TVal>>, and not ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TVal>.
The point is that you only access the Value of the Lazy *after* the correct Lazy object has been returned from the GetOrAdd() - sending in the Value of the Lazy object to the GetOrAdd function defeats the whole purpose of using it.

Edit: Ah - you got it in https://gist.github.com/mennankara/3501446 :)